# Find the N versors more 'spaced'

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, projective-geometry

I have to deal with a concrete problem that is:
Given a 3d object I want to select N directions with N integer and N>=3 for projection that would maximize the information I gain and thus my ability to reconstruct the 3d object from 1d projections

I think (but I am not sure) that this can be translated to a simpler mathematical problem, that I poorly state here as:
In 3d euclidean space, chosen an integer N, I want to find the N versor(unitary vector) maximizing the distance between them.

The 2D equivalent would have solutions expressed in angles for simplicity is:
N=2 -> 0˚, 90˚
N=3 -> 0˚, 60˚, 120˚
N=4 -> 0˚, 45˚, 90˚, 135˚

Suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: Is it possible that your actual question is: "How do I get a uniformly distributed set of points on a sphere?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the [Thomson problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem) should be quite related.

But since you want to restrict yourself to a half sphere, this might be something to have a look at:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44515-generate-non-parallel-axes
[image]